# Problems to find the Lookback options price Analytically

Tags: integration

I have some difficulties with some derivation for a general pricing of a Lookback Put option. I'm using the Björk book "Arbitrage Theory in Continuous Time" and try to follow the setup on page 280 to price a Lookback put option in the Black-Scholes model.

Here is what we know:

$\Pi(0) = e^{-rT}E^Q[max_{t \leq T}S(t) - S(T)]$

$=e^{-rT}E^Q[max_{t \leq T}S(t)] - e^{-rT}E^Q[S(T)]$

$=e^{-rT}E^Q[max_{t \leq T}S(t)] - s$,

if we assume that $S(0) = s$. It remains to compute the term $E^Q[max_{t \leq T}S(t)]$. We have that $S(t)$ is given by

$S(t) = exp(lns + \tilde{r}t + \sigma W ) = e^{X(t)},$

where

$dX = \tilde{r}dt + \sigma W, $

$X(0) = lns$

and

$\tilde{r} = r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2.$

Thus we see that

$M_s(T) = e^{M_X(T)}$

We know the distribution $F$ for $M_X(T)$ from a proposition

$F(x) = N(\frac{x-lns-\tilde{r}T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}) - exp(\frac{2\tilde{r}(x-lns)}{\sigma^2})N(-\frac{x-lns+\tilde{r}T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}) , \forall x \geq lns$

From this expression we may compute the density function $f = F'$ and then we can find

$E^Q[max_{t \leq T}S(t)] = E^Q[e^{M_X(T)}] = \int_{lns}^\infty e^x f(x) dx.$

**After a series of elementary, but extremely tedious, partial integrations we end up with the following result.**

$\Pi(0) = -sN(-d) + se^{-rT}N(-d + \sigma \sqrt{T}) + s \frac{\sigma^2}{2r} N(d)- se^{-rT}\frac{\sigma^2}{2r}N(-d+\sigma \sqrt{T}), $

where $d= \frac{rT+ \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2T}{\sigma \sqrt{T} }$

**My Problem:**

I really can not see how the result is obtained.

I calculated the density function $M_X(T)$ given as

$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}\phi( \frac{x-lns-\tilde{r}T} {\sigma \sqrt{T}} ) - \frac{2\tilde{r}}{\sigma^2} exp(\frac{2\tilde{r}(x-lns)}{\sigma^2}) \Phi( -\frac{x-lns+\tilde{r}T} {\sigma \sqrt{T}} )  + \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{T}} exp(\frac{2\tilde{r}(x-lns)}{\sigma^2}) \phi( -\frac{x-lns+\tilde{r}T} {\sigma \sqrt{T}} ) $

Plugging $f(x)$ in the formula above doesn't give me something near the result.

I tried using partial integration directly

$\int_{lns}^\infty e^x f(x) dx = [e^x F(x)]_{lns}^{\infty} - \int_{lns}^\infty e^x F(x) dx$.

The problem here is that we will get $\infty$ already in the first term.

I hope some of you have an idea and can lead me in the right direction to solve it.

Many thanks in advanced!